# Log in as a user given alternate security identity credentials

Tags: c#, winapi

Our application currently uses LogonUser to allow for a second user to validate a change. This works great with a regular username and password, however we need to use smart cards/pins for some users instead of passwords. Is there anything available to log in using alternate security identity credentials instead of password in the windows API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try looking [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374731%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#smart_card_functions).
As far as i know, [CredUIPromptForWindowsCredentials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375178%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) also support smart cards, etc.

Comment: CredUIPromptForWindowsCredentials is the hint we needed. Calling it to get the credentials then getting the username and password from CredUnPackAuthenticationBuffer we could pass the username and password to LogonUser like we normally would.